# why i do not have sgplot with runing this program in sas 9.2

Tags: data-visualization, sas

```
data a;
input treat$    rep boreria mimiosa asysta  axono   seleria paspa   macran  melas   scopo   cleom   otto;
cards;
M   1   0.20    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    12.20   0.00    0.00    0.00    4.90    0.00
M   2   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.64    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
M   3   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    0.32    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
A   1   0.00    0.00    7.80    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
A   2   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
A   3   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
CA  1   9.40    1.24    1.59    5.20    0.00    1.77    0.00    0.00    0.12    0.00    0.00
CA  2   0.75    0.00    0.00    2.10    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    2.66
CA  3   2.00    0.99    0.00    1.10    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.76    0.00    0.00    0.00
P   1   0.00    0.00    0.00    1.56    0.97    0.00    0.00    0.10    0.00    0.00    0.00
P   2   0.02    0.00    0.00    0.93    0.00    3.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
P   3   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    6.20    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
W   1   13.40   15.80   0.30    104.50  0.00    127.70  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
W   2   4.80    0.00    0.64    121.10  41.10   58.10   0.00    9.20    0.00    0.00    0.59
W   3   0.00    0.00    0.00    53.00   0.00    54.70   0.00    10.10   0.00    0.00    0.00
;
data b;
set a;
array log{*} boreria--otto;
do i = 1 to dim(log);
log(i)=log10(log(i)+1);
end;
output;
drop i;
run;
ods output  Eigenvectors=vector ;
proc princomp out=pcacomp  ;
    VAR boreria--otto;
RUN;

data vec;
set vector (rename = (variable=Weed prin1=vec1 prin2=vec2));
vec1 = vec1*7;
vec2 = vec2*7;
drop prin3-prin10;
run;

data new;
merge pcacomp vec;
run;



ods listing style=statistical image_dpi=300;
proc sgplot data=new;
VECTOR x=vec1 y=vec2/group=weed ARROWHEADSHAPE=filled DATALABEL=weed;
scatter x=prin1 y=prin2 / group=treat name='site';
ellipse x=prin1 y=prin2 / LINEATTRS=(pattern=2) TRANSPARENCY=0.1 ; 
refline 0 /axis=x LINEATTRS=(PATTERN=1);
refline 0 /axis=y LINEATTRS=(PATTERN=1);
xaxis label='PCA1 (32.0%)' grid ;
yaxis label='PCA2 (18.2%)' grid;
KEYLEGEND 'site' /title='Treatment' LOCATION= inside position= topLEFT across=3 noborder; 
run;
```

Comment: Could you please ask a specific question, @bety?  Otherwise this thread will have to be closed.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran your code and it all works fine on my computer.

In SAS 9.2, check the Results/Explorer window and go to Results tab (the bottom of that window) and my guess is, it should created a PNG file of the plot from PROC SGPLOT.

Based on my experience, you cannot open high-resolution graphical outputs in SAS 9.2, but SAS Enterprise Guide can.

[image]

Comment: In addition to @ken 's answer, another method is to use a different ODS destination, such as an rtf file.